# How to put my javascript in the footer

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I just want to ask on how to print script 'javascript' at the footer using simple plugin. I'm using WordPress 3.0 any ideas?

Comment: You can also get that same performance gain by adding a `defer` tag to your scripts - see https://matthewhorne.me/defer-async-wordpress-scripts/

Answer (score 112):

Use a functions.php file inside your theme template add this :

```
<?php

function add_this_script_footer(){ ?>

[YOUR JS CODE HERE]

<?php } 

add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer'); ?>
```

Comment: Sweet. Thanks.

Additionally, though, if you want to make sure it loads after another script, (ie, JQuery) you can add a priority like so: `add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer', 20);`

Comment: To include js code in admin footer, 'admin_footer' action can be used.

Comment: Thanks @EricG for the 3rd parameter.

Comment: I think it's important mentioning that <script> tag wrapping the JS code is required. Without that the snippet will be printed as plain text on the page.

Comment: While this process is one that works, it's not the correct way to do it. Scripts should be added using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action which has an argument to indicate whether to load in the header or footer (see other example).

Answer (score 41):

For an external javascript file to be linked in the footer, use this (>= WP2.8)

```
function my_javascripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'the-script-handle', 
                       'path/to/file.js', 
                       array( 'jquery','other_script_that_we_depend_on' ), 
                       'scriptversion eg. 1.0', 
                       true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_javascripts' );
```

That last true means that the script should be put at the wp_footer() hook.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as this is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 12):

Hum may be it's too late to answer, but if anyone else comes here with the same problem :

There is a plugin to do this : 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/footer-javascript/

Or you can doing this manually by adding this short code in your functions.php :

```
/**
 * Automatically move JavaScript code to page footer, speeding up page loading time.
 */
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
```

Comment: This also moves the styles to the footer

Answer (score 5):

Use a functions.php file inside your theme (or child theme if exists) template add this:

```
function add_this_script_footer() { 
?>
<script>
`enter code here`
</script>
<?php } 
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer');
```