# Wordpress jQuery is not found when using specific theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a shortcode via a plugin which adds a bunch of javascript and html out to a page via the PHP for the plugin.

This works just great on the twentyfourteen theme - and my plugin works as expected.

When I try installing my plugin and using my shortcode in a OptimizePress theme it does not work.

When I attempt it there is a console error stating :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

This is on this line:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() { --this line
        jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
```

This is part of the javascript I add to the page as part of the shortcode.

Interestingly when I look at the source for the page there is certainly jQuery loaded. However, for some reason when I use this shortcode in this theme it has positioned my javascript I echo out as part of the plugin into the  as seen in my picture below (my code is inside the highlighted script tag)- whereas the jQuery doesnt load until the end of the page - which is probably why we hit this error with jQuery not being defined.

[image]

When the shortcode is used in the twentyfourteen theme my javascript output as part of the plugin is contained inline within the body as seen in this pic (the script tag) of the page - meaning it can find jQuery as it will have loaded:

[image]

Can anybody suggest why this is happening and how I can make my javascript sit inline rather than in the  of my document when using shortcodes in OptimizePress to help resolve this error or any other solutions to resolving this problem.

Comment: how do you add the script? if you add it using wp_enqueue_script() then you can add dependencies(like jquery) it should give you some feedback, what happens if you put your code in the footer rather then the header(just for testing)?

Comment: I don't pick where I put it....it seems that the theme chooses that? It is added in functions.php using wp_enqueue_script

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221870/how-to-put-my-javascript-in-the-footer

Comment: That was very very useful thank you alex. Now I have removed the jQuery error - but unfortunately the script relied on php parameters which I was setting via php echo statements. When it is in the functions.php it has no way of accessing my parameters set within the original plugin file? Any ideas how I can work around that?

Comment: code examples are needed probably you can create a new question?

Comment: can add_action be called from any file not just functions.php? If so perhaps I can make it work by just adding that into my original plugin code?

Comment: sure it can, better try/read documentation then just to ask here and wait for answers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66203/discussion-between-renegadeandy-and-alex-alex).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use add_script within my plugin php and add the script to the wp_footer! Many thanks to alex alex for the support. I had to use global keywords within my php plugin to access variables defined outside of the scope of the newly created php function for the add_script call.