# Javascript: How to add an event listener to the body of a CMS, with the JS code in the header

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onclick, content-management-system, event-listener

I wrote a script that adds a listener to a  for an onClick event.  When clicked, it searches the document for any element with a specific class "someclass", and then performs some operations on it etc..

The problem is, after finding all the elements with class="someclass", the array of all the elements with class="someclass" is null.  I think this is because the JS code that adds the listener is in the header, and when it runs, the body (that comes from a different php file from the CMS) that contains the actual  has no yet loaded.

What do I do about this?

A side note, I am trying to do this using pure JS.  I do not want to have anything other than one single external .js file.  So that means no jquery or other API's, and no editing the html.

What are my options here?  Thank you for reading.

Comment: can you post the javascript you have so far? is there a reason its being added to the head and not the body? why not use wordpress's footer method to inject it in to the bottom of the body?

Comment: Yup, coming right up.  I wanted it all to eventually be in one single .js file and be completely unobtrusive.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/45FA3fr2

Here is the code in the header.

The bottom function just calls multiple functions for the window.onload event.

The topmost function is the problem:

`var cmarray = document.getElementsByClassName('commentsection');`
seems to be returning null.  I think because the body hasn't loaded when it's called

Comment: The whole thing is your basic "click a button/div" and another div changes class (and css renders it display:none;), and it updates the content of the button to read "show or hide".

Here is a jsfiddle mock-up:  http://jsfiddle.net/2qt8q2yw/

Comment: here you go:  [javascript in wordpress footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221870/how-to-put-my-javascript-in-the-footer)

Comment: So..., just move ALL javascript to the footer using functions.php to inject it there?

Is there no way to do it so that an external .js file is called?

Comment: No you'd still do it with a external file. i.e. replace `[YOUR JS CODE HERE]` with a self executing function that injects your javascript file. i.e. `var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.setAttribute('src', '/your-script.js');
   script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);`

Comment: I see.  Is that path from the themes directory?

Comment: no, you'd be best to use a wordpress tag `get_template_directory()` to get the right url

Comment: Thanks.  I just stuck it right into the footer.php file right before the close of the body and it all works.  Now I should just be able to merge it all into 1 .js file, and just put:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/mycode.js"></script>`

before the </body> right?

Comment: yep, thats all you'd need

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should move your JS right before the closing body tag. If that's not possible, you need to either use the `DOMContentLoaded` event of the document object or the `load` event of the window object.

Your problem is that the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) of your page isn't ready so your JS code doesn't have anything to access yet. More info here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload

**DOMContentLoaded** (*works in modern Browsers and IE9+*):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
});
```

**Load** (*works in all Browsers*):

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.');
};
```

Comment: But I use window.onload to load both functions, and it still throws the error that the array is null.

Comment: Can you show the example code where the "array" is null? Also which Browser are you testing with?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

googling has led me to believe this is because the <div> tag that one of the functions finds is not loaded by the CMS when the function runs.

Comment: How are you retrieving the element that you're calling `addEventListener` on? Can you show the whole code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ls66r2Au

It's in here

and here is how it's called:

`function addcsbuttonlistener(){
   document.getElementById("comment-hide-button").addEventListener("click", hidecommentsect);
  }`

Comment: It sounds like your issue relates to WordPress and not JavaScript because your element is not even on the page. If you need to remove the JavaScript error, then just check if the element exists before trying to add the event with: `if(el) { el.addEventListener(...); }`.

Comment: It's not just the error.  The div that acts as the button is unclickable because it has no listener.  I wrote all the code here, and I also wrote the theme/loop/etc from scratch as a learning project I guess.

I guess I have to load all the JS in the footer like the other commenter says?

Comment: I don't know much about WordPress but in general you should place scripts at the bottom of the page and make sure that they exist in every page you need them to execute in.

Comment: I just moved everything to the footer (I guess it's the last "part" that the wordpress backbone stitches together), and everything works perfectly....

I just learned HTML/CSS this past week (still working on JS), and all the tutorials and stuff said it goes in the header... :/

Comment: Yeah, don't always trust articles as many tend to be outdated. Good luck learning JS! Here is a link to a free book: http://eloquentjavascript.net/