# How to insert external javascript in Wordpress body?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, header

I'm trying to insert javascript in wordpress but I can only insert in head section. and the script is not working

this is the code I want to insert in wordpress. before closing tag of body.

```
script src="js/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
script src="js/EasePack.min.js"></script>
script src="js/rAF.js"></script>
script src="js/demo-1.js"></script>
```

I want to insert this http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedHeaderBackgrounds/  in to my wordpress.

My wordpress theme is divi 2.4

And how to insert a div section on body. Because in the javascript there's a code

```
    largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
    largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

    canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
```

so I must insert a div in body of my theme.

like this

```
<div id="large-header" class="large-header">
                <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>



                <h1 class="main-title">Connect <span class="thin">Three</span></h1>


            </div><!---- large header --->
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [How to put my javascript in the footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221870/how-to-put-my-javascript-in-the-footer)

Also... Make sure to correctly open your script tags.