# Site breaking down 2 seconds during load

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Hi I have a wordpress [websitse](https://www.ballaratyoga.com.au/). When I try to visit that site it breaks down full layout for minimum 2 seconds. I can't understand why this is happening. I tried to use [Javascript to footer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/footer-javascript/) plugin.

Please suggest me what happened here. And what can I do in this situation.

Comment: I believe it could be due to loading some part of css later. Are you loading css after loading html?

Comment: Your website loads content of more than 9500kB. This takes quite a while to download...

Comment: In your case if website content is large i suggest show `loading...` till website doesn't load completely

Comment: Move all your style sheets attached via `<link>`  in `<head>`. Currently they are in bottom part of page.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Rather then showing a loading indicator, he should optimize his page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see you're using Divi theme in your wordpress site. I believe the above problem is due to loading css at the end of `body`.

When I inspect your site, I am able to see main css file such as Divi/style.css (Parent theme style) is loading at the end of body. Hence I came to this conclusion. Try moving your css to `head` that would solve your problem.

Incase you're concern about site speed try moving css one by one to `head`.

Comment: css should always be loaded ASAP. Delaying loading css will result in the layout jumping around when the files finally load in. And if a css file slows your site down to a crawl, fix your css.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, I believe he is not loading css in head mainly because of google page speed concern or to increase page speed. But yes he should take care of loading necessary css in head if not all css

Comment: @GopinathShiva I just disabled  Javascript to footer  plugin. But when I disabled that render-blocking JavaScript causing. but loading problem solved. Is there any solution?

Comment: @LemonKazi: I have used and would recommend Autoptimize plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/ . Through this plugin you can able to move javascript to footer and has many speed improving benefits. Don't forget to give a tick if my answer helped you solving your problem...

Comment: Thanks I used that. Render blocking reduced but new created JS on render blocking now. OK thanks for help I am trying.

Comment: Add newly created js file in footer using "wp_footer" action http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221870/how-to-put-my-javascript-in-the-footer - this loads js file only in footer

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are writing the `link rel="stylesheet"` which is poor poor practice. Add it in head and your problems will be solved.

Do not write your main stylesheet in body tag, if you do not want that effect.

Further reading

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16844668/17447
2. [load external css file in body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957446/load-external-css-file-in-body-tag)

Comment: Thanks for answering. let me try.

Comment: I just disabled  Javascript to footer  plugin. But when I disabled that render-blocking JavaScript causing. but loading problem solved. Is there any solution?