# Logo is not resizing when I scroll unless I add jquery llink/version to header

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I added a script to have the logo shrink when the page is scrolled.  It will only work when I add the jquery.min.js version script link to the header.  I thought jquery is added to Wordpress and I know doing this can break other things.

Should I add this and if so what is the correct way to add it to Wordpress?

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"         </script> 

    <script> $(document).on('scroll', function() {   $('.logo img').toggleClass('small', $(document).scrollTop() >= 10); });
    </script>
```

This is the development site - https://essey.tfm-dev.com/#!search?width=105&height=70&season_id=all&location_id=28242&search_by=size

Comment: Please include all relevant code (the HTML in this case) *within the question*.   Your HTML is `<img class="logo">` so your selector should be `$("img.logo")` to select.

Comment: Sorry that class should have been removed.  I added that when I was trying to get it to work.  I deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a better selectorthat actually selects your desired element

so instead of `.logo img` you could use `img.logo` for your example (img tag that has class "logo")

when I enter this code into your dev site console it works as expected

```
jQuery(document).on('scroll', function() {   
   jQuery('img.logo').toggleClass('small', jQuery(document).scrollTop() >= 10); 
});
```

you might switch back jQuery to $, i just made it to try out in console

and yes you dont need/ should not include jquery twice, please check the network tab and´make sure it´s loaded once, then [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221870/how-to-put-my-javascript-in-the-footer) how to add your js to your page

Comment: *"selects the element twice"* - that *would* be `$('.logo,img')`  - OPs code, as provided,  does not select the same element twice, it uses hierarchy selection.  Having said that, jquery would only return the object once anyway, example: https://jsfiddle.net/gr7wtsfx/  Maybe OPs off-site code does something different so this fix works.  Looked: it's `<img class='logo'>` so their code is returning *nothing*, not the same element twice.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.  I'm not good with jquery where do I check to see if jquery is loaded?  When you said "please check the network tab and´make sure it´s loaded once" Where is that at?

Comment: I adjusted the code to what you suggested but I'm getting this error in Sources - "Uncaught ReferenceError: $jQuery is not defined"

Comment: Also the console shows that Jquery is loaded I think.  It shows this - jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2.  Does that mean it's added?  If so why does my script only work if I add this to the header - <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>?

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for pointing that out, updated answer accordingly